# iOS : How to create UILabel like news paper style

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel

[image]

Please see the attached image i want to create label in iOS, can anyone help me on this 
First latter is big and other one are small like news paper style.

Comment: HI IosDev: Are you getting the Solution? if yes Please share this. i also want to same thing..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solutions from below link..

https://github.com/C4Code/DropCap

Have a look Enjoy... :-]

Answer (score 0):

this isn't something that you can easily do with a UILabel.  If the text is static, you could make 2 UILabels, one for the first letter, and one for the rest of the text.  Another option is to make a webview and create an html file that you load locally in your project.  In that file you can format the text with HTML/CSS (might be overkill).  Another good solution would be [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which will allow you to do different colors and formatting in one label.

(p.s. if you want people to answer your questions; if you find an answer helpful you should click the checkmark beside the answer.)